# how to disable scrolling NestedScrollView

Tags: flutter, dart

I tried to use `physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()` in NestedScrollView but still yet is still scrolling.

How can disable scrolling in NestedScrollView if the content is not exceeding.

```
NestedScrollView(
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        //
        //AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
          return <Widget>[
            SliverAppBar(
              pinned: true,
              centerTitle: false,
              floating: true,
              stretch: false,
              expandedHeight: 300.0,
              leadingWidth: 100,
              collapsedHeight: 300,
              leading: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 15.0),
                      child: PopupMenuButton(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        offset: Offset(0, 40),
                        itemBuilder: (_) => <PopupMenuItem<String>>[
                          new PopupMenuItem<String>(
                            child: Center(
                              child: Text(
                                'My Event',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              actions: [
                Padding(
                  padding:
                      EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 10.0),
                  child: AnimatedContainer(
                    width: 160,
                    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 150),
                    curve: Curves.easeIn,
                    child: TextField(
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      onTap: () {},
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                        ),
                        contentPadding:
                            EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8, horizontal: 8),
                        suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
                        filled: true,
                        hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[800]),
                        hintText: "Search",
                        fillColor: Colors.grey[100],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
              flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                centerTitle: true,
                title: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                  child: Image.asset(
                    'assets/eventLogo.png',
                  ),
                ),
                background: Image.asset(
                  'assets/newEvent.png',
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SliverPersistentHeader(
              delegate: _SliverAppBarDelegate(
                TabBar(
                  labelColor: Colors.black87,
                  unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey,
                  tabs: [
                    Tab(text: "Popular"),
                    Tab(text: "Music"),
                    Tab(text: "Sport"),
                    Tab(text: "Movie"),
                    Tab(text: "Other"),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              pinned: true,
            ),
          ];
        },
        body: TabBarView(
          children: [
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 20,
                  ),
                  Text("This Week"),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 20,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    height: 300,
                    width: 300,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                      color: Colors.red,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Icon(Icons.directions_transit),
            Icon(Icons.directions_bike),
            Center(
              child: Text("Sample text"),
            ),
            Center(
              child: Text("Sample text"),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: it would be good to share your code

Comment: @JahidulIslam i have share the code

Answer (score 2):

I didn't find any solution to disable the scrolling in the **body** of the `NestedScrollView`. Instead I came across the solution which makes the less content in the **body** not to scroll below the `headerSliverBuilder` slivers list.

The solution is that using the combination of `SliverOverlapAbsorber` and `SliverSafeArea` for the `headerSliverBuilder` slivers list and set `handle` property of `SliverOverlapAbsorber` with

```
NestedScrollView.sliverOverlapAbsorberHandleFor(context)
```

**Note:** In a single NestedScrollView we can use only one `SliverOverlapAbsorber`. If you have multiple slivers in `headerSliverBuilder` then try adding them in `SliverList` or `MultiSliver`(from [sliver_tools](https://pub.dev/packages/sliver_tools) package) which considers dynamic height for its children. and wrapping it with `SliverOverlapAbsorber` and `SliverSafeArea`.

For example:

```
SliverOverlapAbsorber(
 handle:NestedScrollView.sliverOverlapAbsorberHandleFor(context),
 sliver: SliverSafeArea(
            sliver: MultiSliver(
                        [
                         SliverAppBar(),
                         SliverAppBar(),
                         SliverToBoxAdapter(),
                        ],
                     ),//end of MultiSliver
                    ),//end of SliverSafeArea
               ),//end of SliverOverlapAbsorber
```

Comment: can you show the complete code, did you add the SliverOverlapAbsorber() as the only child of the headerSliverBuilder()