# Flutter - NestedScrollView's Body disappear under AppBar / Slivers

Tags: flutter, flutter-sliver, nestedscrollview

Why is the default behavior of a NestedScrollView to "scroll body" beyond app bar? And to have a body of X pixels is not respected neither.

How do you make the Container / Body widget not scroll beyond Sliver since it's obvious it doesn't need to do that. It's just one text. If the content is actually bigger than the body - then yes, it should scroll.

It's the same using SliverFillRemaining inside the Sliver - it takes "more" than what remains.

**Example Code:**

```
return Scaffold(
  body: NestedScrollView(
    headerSliverBuilder: (context, innerBoxIsScrolled) {
      return [
        SliverAppBar(
          pinned: true,
          title: Text("AppBar Title")
        )
      ];
    },
    body: Container(
      color: Colors.blue,
      height: 100, // Value not respected
      child: Text("This will disappear"),
    ),
  ),
);
```

**Example Behaviour:**

I can scroll the body beyond AppBar and then it's just gone. I can't find a reason for this to be the default behaviour.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you dont need `NestedScrollView` while there is no scrollable widget inside it

Comment: In my opinion I don't think we can disable the scrolling in NestedScrollView but I found one similar answer, you can check it out by this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71996012/15638854

Comment: @YeasinSheikh It's still the same if there's one item. I can't even resize the body at all. Changing out the widgets based on the view being empty seems like alot of workarounds. Also - there's suppose to be tabs with multiple pages beside eachother here as well. One body might be empty - while the other one's not. The same issue remains - when there's less content than the body's height + offset, content just disappear. Perhaps this was just an example to demonstrate an issue that occurs while using NestedScrollView. I suggest Google remove it's if it's not meant to be used.

Comment: if you are referring while container taking full height, because size goes up on container.   For your question case, you can use SingleChildScrolVIew

Comment: @YeasinSheikh Still the same with any Widget. In this case I took the simplest example to demonstrate the issue - a Container. In my real example I have a TabBarView with SafeArea -> Builder -> CustomScrollView -> SliverToBoxAdapter -> Columns with perhaps 1 item or perhaps 200. Same issue.

Comment: @CavinMacwan Code in that example actually helped.

Comment: I mean with removing the `NestedScrollView`

Comment: SingleChildScrollView doesn't support slivers which is the reason this occurs and the reason I'm using this is because I need scrollable / pinnable Slivers.